# Getting nth:child of specific element type

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

Example code:

```
<div id="top">
    <h1></h1>
    <div></div>
    <h2></h2>
    <div>Get this one</div>
    <h3></h3>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

So i know that i can get this using

```
$('#top:nth-child(4)').etc...
```

but can i get this by saying "get the second child that is a div element" rather than just "get the fourth child element"?

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: `$('#top:nth-child(4)')` would select an element with id `#top` that would also be the 4th child of its parent. `$('#top > :nth-child(4)')` will select that div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with `nth-of-type`, which relates to the tag type itself (in this case `div`), not to classes or child elements in general:

```
$('#top > div:nth-of-type(2)').etc.
```

ADDITION after additional question in comment:

You can't select the nth DIV with a certain class with CSS selectors, but using jQuery.

```
$("#top > div.x").eq(1).css("color", "blue");
```

`eq()` selects the nth element in the collection (i.e. in the selection made before). Note that its index starts at 0, so `eq(1)`selects the second element in the collection:

```js
$("#top > div.x").eq(1).css("color", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top">
    <h1>H1</h1>
    <div class="x">1st DIV with class "x"</div>
    <h2>H2</h2>
    <div>DIV</div>
    <h3>H3</h3>
    <div>DIV</div>
    <div class="x">2nd DIV with class "x"</div>
    <h2>H2</h2>
    <div>DIV</div>
    <h3>H3</h3>
    <div class="x">3rd DIV with class "x"</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about if i wanted to be even more specific and say div with a certain class? is that doable? Would it be $('#top > div.classname:nth-of-type(2)') ?

Comment: that's not possible with CSS selectors

Comment: Please note that i added a working solution for your second answer

Answer (score 1):

`$('#top > div')[1]` or `$('#top > div').get(1)` will do what you want.  It says "grab the divs *immediately* inside #top, and then select the 2nd one." `$('#top div')` (along with `.get(1)`) would produce the same result in this case, but that would mean "grab all divs that are descendents of #top", i.e., even #top > div > div#depth2 would be counted.

As Johannes pointed out, `$('#top > div:nth-of-type(2)')` is a shortcode for this, but I would get familiar with the basics first - you can select immediate children of type with a caret (>) and all descendents of type with a space ( ).

Comment: No problem, plz mark as answer if this solved your issue. <3

Comment: With regard to your comment about classnames, this is when using traditional arrays or `.get()` is faster than the :shortcuts.  E.g., `$('#top > div.classname').get(n)`.

Comment: I asked a further question in the comment on Johannes reply. If you know the answer feel free to reply though :)

Comment: Ha! Beat you to it!

Comment: Beat me to it :D. So the div.classname example is a valid one then?

Comment: is get() faster than eq() ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#top').children('div').eq(1).html()
```

Above line implies; if you count from 0, get the 2nd div which is a child of `top` div.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use selector nth-of-type(number). Here's for you

CSS

```
#top > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  /*Your css*/
}
```

or in Jquery

```
$("#top > div:nth-of-type(2)").method();
```

Btw, it's a same selector. I just use css `nth-of-type(2)` selector on Jquery selector